# Height of the item view gets reduced when i scroll on Recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, vertical-text

I want to show name list.I am using recylerview to show that.For that I've used Vertical TextView as a item view.it works properly.But the problem is when i scroll the recyclerview,the items height gets reduced

VerticalTextview class

```
public class VerticalTextView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView {
    boolean topDown;

    public boolean getTopDown(){
        return topDown;
    }
    public void setTopDown(boolean key){
        this.topDown=key;
    }

    public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        final int gravity = getGravity();

        if(Gravity.isVertical(gravity) && (gravity&Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
            setGravity((gravity&Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP);
            topDown = false;
        }else
            topDown = true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(),getMeasuredWidth());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        TextPaint tp =getPaint();
        tp.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
        tp.drawableState=getDrawableState();
        canvas.save();

        if(topDown){
            canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
            canvas.rotate(90);
        }else {
            canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
            canvas.rotate(-90);
        }

        canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());

        getLayout().draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();



    }
}
```

This is my item layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:sayaki="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:visibility="visible"

      android:layout_marginVertical="5dp">


        <VerticalTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sub_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sathyan"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingVertical="1dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />


  </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

but while scrolling the item height gets reduced.

this is the before scrolling:
[image]
After scrolling:
[image]
you can see that last 3 items height is reduced and some c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.I just changed my vertical TextView class like below

```
public class NewVerticalView extends TextView {
    private Rect bounds = new Rect();
    private TextPaint textPaint;
    private int color;

    public NewVerticalView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NewVerticalView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        color = getCurrentTextColor();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        textPaint = getPaint();
        textPaint.getTextBounds((String) getText(), 0, getText().length(), bounds);
        setMeasuredDimension((int) (bounds.height() + textPaint.descent()), bounds.width());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        textPaint.setColor(color);
        canvas.rotate(-90,bounds.width(),0
        );
        canvas.drawText((String) getText(), 0,- bounds.width() + bounds.height(), textPaint);
    }
}
```

and added the rotation as 180 in the xml.Now my problem is solved.